# PHP decoded JSON - Make output more user friendly

Tags: php, json

I am decoding a .json file with PHP. I have successfully put the json data into a html table.

The json data is in the form of:
`{..."id.type.subtype":value,"id.type.subtype2":value,"id.type1.subtype":value,...}`

This is displayed in my HTML table as:
`<tr><td>id.type.subtype</td><td>value</td></tr>`

I want to convert each unique `id.type.subtype` into a unique human readable name like `Thing`.

My full code:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('file.json');
$jsonIterator = new  
 RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),     RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
if (count($jsonIterator) > 0) { 
echo "<table>\n";
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) { 
if(is_array($val)) { 
    $cnt = count($val); 
    echo "<tr><td>$key</td></tr>\n"; 
} else { 
    echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>$val</td></tr>\n"; 
    } 
}
echo "</table>\n\n"; 
} else {
echo "<p>The iterator is empty.</p>"; 
}
?>
```

Placing the following just after the `foreach()` is the only method I can think of. It works but would need an if/elseif for the 200-300 different keys

```
if ($key == 'id.type.subtype') {
$key = 'Thing';
}
```

I haven't used PHP for quite a long time. I understand that any method would require manually inputting each user friendly title, but there must be a more code efficient method of changing the keys. Is there another way?

Comment: That code hurts my eyes even though I should be happy you are trying to use SPL.  Perhaps try and clean up the array to look the way you want when dumped out, then worry about rendering it out as a table.  Doing it as two steps also might help you figure this out yourself.  side note: why "foreach", then a "for count"...?

Comment: `$keys = array('id.type.subtype' => 'Thing', ...);` then `$keys[$key]`

Comment: You can ignore the for count. I removed code that wasn't required in order to make the question easier to read, I just missed some.

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey That's what I was aiming for. It works fine. Will try it on my actual script and see well it goes. I'm still open to other suggestions. I haven't used PHP for years, so I'm using this project to relearn it.